# Removing COM Ports in Windows programmatically (Setup API ? )

Tags: c#, c++, windows, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I'm looking for a way of programmatically removing virtual COM ports created by multiple bluetooth pairing processes. Ideally, I would like to map every new paired device ( only on at once) to the same virtual port. Can this be done via the windows setup api ?

Thanks,
             dinsdale

Comment: Get friendly with the WMI classes...

Comment: any suggestion where to look first ? I know WMI mostly for retrieving system information ( as most examples show). Do you know resources explaining system configuration itself ?

Comment: I'm not sure which class exactly represents a COM port, but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(VS.85).aspx) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the devcon source code in the windows DDK. I've attached the readme so you can see that it has source to do exactly what you want -- disable a serial port.

DevCon Sample

DEVCON

DevCon is a command-line tool that displays detailed information about devices, and lets you search for and manipulate devices from the command line. DevCon enables, disables, installs, configures, and removes devices on the local computer and displays detailed information about devices on local and remote computers. DevCon is included in the Windows DDK.

ABOUT THIS DOCUMENT

This document describes the DevCon source code, which is included in the Windows DDK in the /src/setup/devcon directory. It explains the DevCon design, and describes how to use the SetupAPI and device installation functions to enumerate devices and perform device operations in a console application.

For a complete description of DevCon features and instructions for using them, see the DevCon help file in the DDK documentation in Driver Development Tools/Tools for Testing Drivers/DevCon.

SCOPE

These instructions pertain to Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. DevCon was designed for use on Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003. It will not work on Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows ME.

HOW IT WORKS

Running "devcon help" will provide a list of commands along with short descriptions of what each command does. "devcon help " will give more detailed help on that command. The interpretation of each command is done via a dispatch table "DispatchTable" that is at the bottom of "cmds.cpp". Some of the commands make use of a generic device enumerator "EnumerateDevices". A few of these commands will work when given a remote target computer, and will also work if using the 32-bit devcon on Wow64.  A description of some of the more interesting functions and the APIs they use follows:

cmdClasses

This command demonstrates the use of SetupDiBuildClassInfoListEx to enumerate all device class GUID's. The function SetupDiClassNameFromGuidEx and SetupDiGetClassDescriptionEx are used to obtain more information about each device class.

cmdListClass

This command demonstrates the use of SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameEx to enumerate one or more class GUID's that match the class name. This command also demonstrates the use of SetupDiGetClassDevsEx to list all the devices for each class GUID.

cmdFind cmdFindAll cmdStatus

A simple use of EnumerateDevices (explained below) to list devices and display different levels of information about each device. Note that all but cmdFindAll use DIGCF_PRESENT to only list information about devices that are currently present. The main functionality for these and related devices is done inside FindCallback.

cmdEnable cmdDisable cmdRestart

These commands show how to issue DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE to enable a device, disable a device, or restart a device. The main functionality for each of these commands is done inside ControlCallback.

These operations cannot be done on a remote machine or in the context of Wow64. CFGMGR32 API's should not be used as they skip class and co-installers.

cmdUpdate

This command shows how to use UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices to update the driver for all devices to a specific driver. Normally INSTALLFLAG_FORCE would not be specified allowing UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices to determine if there is a better match already known. It's specified in DevCon to allow DevCon to be used more effectively as a debugging/testing tool. This cannot be done on a remote machine or in the context of Wow64.

cmdInstall

A variation of cmdUpdate to install a driver when there is no associated hardware. It creates a new root-enumerated device instance and associates it with a made up hardware ID specified on the command line (which should correspond to a hardware ID in the INF). This cannot be done on a remote machine or in the context of Wow64.

cmdRemove

A command to remove devices. Plug & Play devices that are removed will reappear in response to cmdRescan. The main functionality of this command is in RemoveCallback that demonstrates the use of DIF_REMOVE. This cannot be done on a remote machine or in the context of Wow64. CFGMGR32 API's should not be used as they skip class and co-installers.

cmdRescan

This command shows the correct way to rescan for all Plug & Play devices that may have previously been removed, or that otherwise require a rescan to detect them.

cmdDPAdd

This command allows you to add a Driver Package to the machine.  The main functionality of this command demonstrates the use of SetupCopyOEMInf. Adding a Driver Package to the machine doesn’t mean the drivers are installed on devices, it simply means the drivers are available automatically when a new device is plugged in or a existing device is updated.

cmdDPDelete

This command allows you to uninstall a Driver Package from the machine.  The main functionality of this command demonstrates the use of SetupUninstallOEMInf. Removing a Driver Package from the machine does not uninstall the drivers associated with a device. If you want to accomplish both then use cmdRemove on all the devices using a given Driver Package and then cmdDPDelete to remove the Driver Package itself from the machine. This functionality is not available in Windows 2000 or earlier.

cmdDPEnum

This command allows you to enumerate all of the 3rd party Driver Packages currently installed on the machine and also shows you how to get some common properties from a Driver Package (Provider, Class description, DriverVer date and version).

cmdDPEnumLegacy

This command shows you how to enumerate 3rd party Driver Packages on Windows Server 2003 and earlier operating systems.

Reboot

This function shows how to correctly reboot the machine from a hardware install program. In particular it passes flags to ExitWindowsEx that cause the reboot to be associated with hardware installation. You should never reboot the machine unnecessarily.

EnumerateDevices

Demonstrates the use of SetupDiGetClassDevsEx to enumerate all devices or all present devices, either globally or limited to a specific setup class. Demonstrates the use of SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoListEx to create a blank list associated with a class or not (for most cases, a blank list need not be associated with a class). Demonstrates the use of SetupDiOpenDeviceInfo to add a device instance into a device info list. These last two API's are ideal to obtain a DeviceInfoData structure from a device instance and machine name when mixing CFGMGR32 API's with SETUPAPI API's. SetupDiGetDeviceInfoListDetail is called to obtain a remote machine handle that may be passed into CFGMGR32 API's. SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo is called to enumerate each and every device that is in the device info list (either explicitly added, or determined by the call to SetupDiGetClassDevsEx). The instance ID is obtained by calling CM_Get_Device_ID_Ex, using information in devInfo (obtained from SetupDiEnumerateDeviceInfo) and devInfoListDetail (obtained from SetupDiGetDeviceInfoListDetail). GetHwIds is called to obtain a list of hardware and compatible ID's (explained below). Once an interesting device has been determined (typically by checking hardware ID's) then the callback is called to operate on that individual device.

GetHwIds

Shows how to get the complete list of hardware ID's or compatible ID's for a device using SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.

GetDeviceDescription

Shows how to obtain descriptive information about a device. The friendly name is used if it exists, otherwise the device description is used.

DumpDeviceWithInfo

Shows how to obtain an instance ID (or use any CFGMGR32 API) given HDEVINFO (device info list) and PSP_DEVINFO_DATA (device info data).

DumpDeviceStatus

Shows how to interpret the information returned by CM_Get_DevNode_Status_Ex. Refer to cfg.h for information returned by this API.

DumpDeviceResources

Shows how to obtain information about resources used by a device.

DumpDeviceDriverFiles

Provided as a debugging aid, obtains information about the files apparently being used for a device. It uses SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList to obtain information about the driver being used for the specified device. The driver list associated with a device may be enumerated by calling SetupDiEnumDriverInfo. In this case, there will be no more than one driver listed. This function proceeds to obtain a list of files that would normally be copied for this driver using DIF_INSTALLDEVICEFILES. SetupScanFileQueue is used to enumerate the file queue to display the list of files that are associated with the driver.

DumpDeviceDriverNodes

Provided as a debugging aid, this function determines the list of compatible drivers for a device. It uses SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList to obtain the list of compatible drivers. In this case, all drivers are enumerated, however typically DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV and SetupDiGetSelectedDriver would be used together to find which driver the OS would consider to be the best.

DumpDeviceStack

This function determines class and device upper and lower filters.

BUILDING THE DEVCON SAMPLE

To build the devcon sample:

1. Click the Build Environment icon of choice in the Development Kits Build Environments sub-menu. This will set up the correct build environment to build this sample. Note that this sample will build in the 64-bit environments as well as the 32-bit environments.
2. In a command window, change to the directory containing the DevCon source code. For example:

cd src\setup\devcon

1. Use the macro BLD or run the following from the command prompt:

build –c

This invokes the Microsoft make routines that produce the Build.log, Build.wrn, and Build.err log files.

When the build completes, the executable will be placed in the ObjXXX\I386 subdirectory of the  directory specified in the Sources file (depending on build environment chosen).

If the build does not succeed, check for these errors: 1) the build environment is not set up properly, or 2) modifications made to the sample source code introduced errors.

USING DEVCON

DevCon is provided in ready-to-run form in tools\devcon. For usage, refer to the document provided with devcon.exe. DevCon is a command line utility with built-in documentation available by typing "devcon help".

TESTING

Type "devcon find *" to list device instances of all present devices on the local machine.

Type "devcon status @root\rdp_mou\0000" to list status of the terminal server mouse driver.

Type "devcon status *PNP05*" to list status of all COM ports.

Comment: Hi Ivan, looks very promising ! Thanks